# How do I check which button was pressed after another one?

Tags: objective-c, button, if-statement

I want to check which button is pressed after another one but only after that button has been pressed. e.g. if a button saying cow on it is pressed then a button with a picture of a cow is pressed it displays a tick but not if a picture of a pig is then pressed?

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

Set tags for each button and add a single target method for when any of the button is clicked. When a button is clicked, the target method will get called. In the method, you can check the tag of the button that was currently clicked. You can save the tag to an instance variable. When the next button is clicked, again the target method is called and you can compare the new tag with the previously clicked button tag and apply your logic.

Comment: Sorry, but i am a complete newbie so can you explain how i would do that